# Vcard parser with Python

Tags: python, parsing, vcf-vcard

I am parsing my vcard info (copied to a txt file)to extract `name:number` and put it into a dictionary.

Data sample:

```
BEGIN:VCARD  
VERSION:2.1  
N:MEO;Apoio;;;  
FN:Apoio MEO  
TEL;CELL;PREF:1696  
TEL;CELL:162 00  
END:VCARD  
BEGIN:VCARD  
VERSION:2.1  
N:estrangeiro;Apoio MEO;no;;  
FN:Apoio MEO no estrangeiro  
TEL;CELL;PREF:+35196169000  
END:VCARD
```

```
import re
file = open('Contacts.txt', 'r')
contacts = dict()

    for line in file:
            name = re.findall('FN:(.*)', line)
            nm = ''.join(name)

            if len(nm) == 0:
                continue
            contacts[nm] = contacts.get(nm)
    print(contacts)
```

With this I am getting a dictionary with names but for numbers I am getting None. `{'name': None, 'name': None}`.

Can I do this with re? To extract both name and number with the same `re.findall` expression?

Comment: `contacts[nm] = contacts.get(nm)` of course this gives you None..

Comment: hint on this, please

Comment: Perhaps if you posted a portion of the contents of 'contacts.txt' (with personal data removed, of course), you might get more helpful responses.

Comment: At the point you call `contacts.get(nm)`, `nm` is not in the dict so it returns None. The question, then, is what values do you want in the contacts dict?

Comment: I'm getting to the point @tdelaney I want to put in my dict the data like name:number

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit 2023: the vobject library [hasn't been updated since 2018](https://github.com/eventable/vobject/commits/master), I do not recommend to work with that one, as I believe there should be more modern and better alternatives. Though, I do not know that better one, so please if you have any recommendation, tell it in a comment.

You should better use an already [existing library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject/) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel:

```
pip install vobject
```

And then within python

```
>>> import vobject
>>> s = """\
... BEGIN:VCARD
... VERSION:2.1
... N:MEO;Apoio;;;
... FN:Apoio MEO
... TEL;CELL;PREF:0123456789
... TEL;CELL:0123456768
... END:VCARD
... BEGIN:VCARD
... VERSION:2.1
... N:estrangeiro;Apoio MEO;no;;
... FN:Apoio MEO no estrangeiro
... TEL;CELL;PREF:+0123456789
... END:VCARD """
>>> vcard = vobject.readOne(s)
>>> vcard.prettyPrint()
 VCARD
    VERSION: 2.1
    TEL: 1696
    TEL: 162 00
    FN: Apoio MEO
    N:  Apoio  MEO
```

and you're done!

so if you want to make a dictionary out of that, all you need to do is:

```
>>> {vcard.contents['fn'][0].value: [tel.value for tel in vcard.contents['tel']] }
{'Apoio MEO': ['1696', '162 00']}
```

so you could make all that into a function:

```
def parse_vcard(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        vcard = vobject.readOne(f.read())
        return {vcard.contents['fn'][0].value: [tel.value for tel in vcard.contents['tel']] }
```

From there, you can improve the code to handle multiple `vcard`s in a single `vobject` file, and update the `dict` with more phones.

N.B.: I leave you as an exercise to change the code above from reading one and only one vcard within a file, into a code that can read several vcards. Hint: [read the documentation of `vobject`](http://eventable.github.io/vobject/).

N.B.: I'm using your data, and I'm considering that whatever you wrote, it is meaningless. But in doubt, I have modified the phone numbers.

---

just for the fun, let's have a look at your code. First there's an indentation issue, but I'll consider this is because of bad copy/paste ☺.

```
① import re
② file = open('Contacts.txt', 'r')
③ contacts = dict()

④ for line in file:
⑤     name = re.findall('FN:(.*)', line)
⑥     nm = ''.join(name)

⑦     if len(nm) == 0:
⑧         continue
⑨     contacts[nm] = contacts.get(nm)

⑩ print(contacts)
```

so first, there are two issues at line ②. You're opening a file using `open()`, but you're not closing the file. If you're calling this function to open one billion files, you'll starve your system's available file descriptors because you're not closing the files. As a good habit you should always use instead the with construct:

```
with open('...', '...') as f:
    … your code here …
```

that takes care of the fd for you, and better shows where you can make use of your opened file.

The second issue is that you're calling your variable `file`, which is shadowing the `file` type. Hopefully, the `file` type is very rarely used, but it's a bad habit to have, as you might one day not understand a bug that happens because you've shadowed a type with a variable. Just don't use it, it'll save you trouble one day.

Line ⑤ and ⑥, you're applying a `re.findall` regex on each line. You should better use `re.match()`, as you're already iterating over each line, and you won't have `FN: something` within that line. That will make you avoid the unnecessary `''.join(name)` But instead of using a regex for such a simple thing, you'd better use `str.split()`:

```
if 'FN:' in line:
    name = line.split(':')[-1]
```

Line ⑦ is not only superfluous — if you use the `if` above, but actually wrong. Because then you'll skip all lines that does not have `FN:` within it, meaning that you'll never extract the phone numbers, just the name.

Finally Line ⑧ makes absolutely no sense. Basically, what you're doing is equivalent of:

```
if nm in contacts.keys():
    contacts[nm] = contacts[nm]
else:
    contacts[nm] = None
```

All in all, in your code, all you do is extract names, and you don't even bother with the telephones number. So when you say:

> *With this I am getting a dictionary with names but for numbers I am getting None*

it makes no sense, as you're actually not trying to extract phone numbers.

> *Can I do this with re? To extract both name and number with the same `re.findall` expression?*

yes, you could, with something that would look like (untested regex that's very likely to be not working), over the whole file, or at least for each vcard:

```
FN:(?P<name>[^\n]*).*TEL[^:]*:(?P<phone>[^\n])
```

but why bother, when you've got a lib that does it perfectly for you!

Comment: thanks for your time @zmo ! Your answer is excelent! At this time I'm trying to get all the vcards. Thanks for your analysis of my code. I'm starting to study this data structures of Python... I have to go deeper in dictionaries

Comment: it must be `vcard.prettyPrint()` (i.e. with brackets) in the code listing

Comment: thanks, and fixed! (though, technically, those are parenthesis not brackets ;-) )

Comment: I have used this answer for my project and it is working like a charm! Thanks! By the way I have modified the part where vCard data has been changed into dict. `vcard_values = {i: vcard.contents[i][0].value for i in vcard.contents}`

Comment: Well. I got just one issue with vobject: looks like it don't understand version 2.1, just 3.0. That's why `TEL;WORK;VOICE:XXX` and `TEL;CELL;VOICE:YYY` both are just `tel`, but not `tel.work` and `tel.cell`. I see workaround only change string from `TEL;WORK` to `TEL;TYPE=WORK` and than access type by `v.tel.type_param`.

Comment: That library has been left untouched since 2018 and tbh it actually doesnt do that much for you, if you looked at syntax, even after telling it the first name last name you have to give it the whole name again. and rest of it the same, it is not really the wheel, it is the guy telling you how the wheel looks like

Comment: It's sad it's been that long that lib has been left untouched, and I hope there's a better one available now. My still comment stays, parsing a VCard manually is counterproductive, one should use the best library for the task.

Answer (score 13):

My answer is based on zmos answer (you need to install vobject).

To get all vobjects from a vcf-file you can do something like this:

```
import vobject
with open(infile) as inf:
    indata = inf.read()
    vc = vobject.readComponents(indata)
    vo = next(vc, None)
    while vo is not None:
        vo.prettyPrint()
        vo = next(vc, None)
```

The documentation of `vobject` (on GitHub) is a little bit crappy so I looked into their code and figured out that `readOne` is just calling a next on `readComponents`. So you can use `readComponents` to get a collection.